# Employer giving away Personal Information

Tags: employer-relations

I just found out that my employer has been giving out personal information to third parties. I understand where that is acceptable in cases where a outside company is contracted to perform payroll, insurance and other services the company buys. Although at times it seems that my company is being very liberal with our personal information.

Shouldn't companies consent their employees first before giving personal information to third parties? (I believe the answer is no, but haven't found much in searching the internet)

Are they allowed to sell employee personal information?

How can I ask them to be more cautious when working with our personal information with making a huge dramatization of the issue? (Rephrase: Whats the best way to broach the subject?)

Are there specific pieces of personal information they are allowed or not allowed to share by law?

Comment: Some of your questions are legal ones, and probably outside the scope of this site.

Comment: It might be some of those third parties sharing the information too.

Comment: Ask your HR department and/or look over your contract/documentation.

Comment: Which pieces of personal information are we talking about? Some are a matter of public record, after all.

Comment: I'd check my work contract if I were you. Something might be written about it there...

Comment: Make sure it was actually the company's decision to give away that information. In one company I worked for, an executive assistant had given the employee directory to her husband for his own personal business, but no one had authorized her to do such a thing.